# Timing: Would listening to a metronome for hours on end help at all?

Tags: rhythm, ear-training

Adam Neely, my new favorite music Youtube person, suggests listening to a metronome for hours on end to improve your sense of rhythm/timing/tempo.

If my goal is to improve my internal sense of rhythm, is this a viable method? What other methods are there?

Comment: I think I agree with the answers given here that more active listening is likely to produce better results, but I'm going to take my metronome into the office anyway... sure my colleagues won't mind.

Answer (score 6):

Listening to drum tracks would be less tedious, with other little patterns going on in between the main pulses.

Actually playing with others is probably the most productive.

Putting on tracks to play along to is an excellent way, or to sharpen up *all* of your playing, put the radio on and play along with everything that gets broadcast.

With the track or radio idea, purely for rhythm practice, tap along to whatever's on, turn off the sound for a couple of bars, then on again, checking you're still in time. Increase the silent time.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose having a metronome click as constant background to your daily activity wouldn't do any harm!  But PLAY with a metronome or, for more musical effect, a drum machine.   For several years my bread-and-butter gig was playing clubs on keyboard/drum box with a vocalist.  Then I had a job alongside a superb and very experienced drummer.  He complimented me on my time.  If this was true, I put it down to the years of playing to a drum box.

Comment: Certainly agree with playing along with a drum machine. Did it for several years and, yes, it pays off. Trouble then is, I expect every drummer to keep just as good timing! +1.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion (from either a website or book on ballroom dancing, I forgot which) is to play music with a particular sound on your automobile sound system. I use some strict-temp dance recordings. You get to hear some and at the same time develop a sense of rhythm. This is especially useful on long road trips or while commuting. Listening to waltzes or tangos or rumbas several times will give you a sense of the type of rhythms used and their timing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might benefit from listening to a metronome, but there are many more active ways to develop a sense of rhythm that you might find more appealing. Almost any activity you can count steps of, such as dancing, 1 - 2 - 3 - 4, or waltzing, 1 - 2 - 3, listening to recorded music and counting the beat, just like dancing,  military marching (if you're in the service), even walking down the sidewalk and counting the beat, all more appealing to me, and probably just as effective because when you're counting, you'll probably be focused on the rhythm. Really quite simple isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but I doubt it. What really helps is playing a song to a metronome. Practicing to make sure downbeats are followed and timing is followed, etc.

For me, just listening to a metronome by itself is the equivalent of practicing piano by "forming" chords on your flat desk.